# ListView image selector stays in place when scrolled

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview, selector

I'm having trouble where my `ListView` image selector stays in place even the item selected is no longer visible when scrolled.
[image]

```
1st photo: Selected "One"
2nd photo: Scrolled up, a little of the brown selector is visible
3rd photo: Scrolled up again, brown selector is at "Eleven" position
4th photo: Scrolled up again, the same happens
```

Why does this happen? I want to use `listView.setSelector` since it is already the ListView's method.

Here's my layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".EighthActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/listview_instructor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:dividerHeight="1.5dp" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here's my code:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_eighth);

    ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_instructor);
    listView.setSelector(R.drawable.bg_brown);

    // Defined Array values to show in ListView
    String[] values = new String[] { "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five",
            "Six", "Seven", "Eight", "Nine", "Ten", "Eleven", "Twelve",
            "Thirteen", "Fourteen", "Fifteen", "Sixteen", "Seventeen",
            "Eighteen", "Nineteen", "Twenty" };

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, values);

    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Did anyone also encounter this?

Comment: Similar Question - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36697055/android-listselector-still-partly-visible-when-the-item-is-scrolled-out

Answer (score 0):

try below code:-

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/list" 
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_gravity="center"
      android:divider="@null" 
      android:dividerHeight="0dip"
      android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />
```

Comment: Declaring the `ListView` selector in the layout does not have any effect, it still has the same outcome. Is this common to others that uses `ListView` selectors?