# Android listSelector still partly visible when the item is scrolled out

Tags: android, listview

The image shows the problem: `Venus` item is scrolled out but it's selection is visible.

[image: Venus item is scrolled out but it's selection is visible]

I've looked at [Hanged listSelector in ListView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755088/hanged-listselector-in-listview) and I'm using shapes/gradient as it was advised, but still no luck.

Device: MS VS Emulator for Android, Android 4.2 XHDPI API-17
IDE: Android Studio 2. on Windows 7 WM.

Layout,  main activity

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
        android:scrollingCache="false"
        android:animationCache="false"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

list selector

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/item_pressed" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/item_selected" />
</selector>
```

drawables, item_pressed

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:endColor="#0000ff"
        android:startColor="#0000ff" />

</shape>
```

item_selected

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle" >
    <gradient
        android:angle="90"
        android:endColor="#00ff00"
        android:startColor="#00ff00" />

</shape>
```

And activity code

```
package com.example.listdemo;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class MainActivity extends ListActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.Planets, R.layout.myitem);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

where `Planets` is just an array of strings (Sun, Mercury, Venus, Earth, Mars, Jupiter...) and `myitem` is just a `TextView` with custom height.

Where am I wrong, please?

**EDIT** 
To clarify the question, it's about default list selection behavior. That is about list selector item with no `android:state_xxx` attributes. Don't pay much attention to corresponding drawable name. I'm ready to rename `@drawable/item_selected` to `@drawable/item_default`. Let me know if it will help to clarify the problem and I'll rename it.

Comment: Use custom array adapter to change the background of list items. If you create custom array adapter you will more feasibility to set the background of items and width & height.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr** Don't set a default Drawable on your list selector.

This problem arises when you give the list selector a default Drawable. By this I mean within your list selector definition, you have an `item` tag with no state requirement which makes that `item` inadvertently the **default** Drawable. You can read more about selectors [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html).

Your list selector code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/item_pressed" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/item_selected" /> <-- this is what I'm referring to
</selector>
```

**The fix**

The issue you were having is caused by the list selector always being drawn (even if the selector isn't on screen). Normally this isn't an issue since the list selector is transparent (and thus invisible). However since you gave the list selector a default background, this meant that whenever the list selector was on screen, it would be visible causing the weird behavior you observed. Instead what you really want is to only show this background when an item is actually selected.

To do this, first we must remove the default background from the list selector. Then we need a new way to indicate selected items. Since you specified `android:choiceMode="singleChoice"` in your ListView, the ListView will treat your list items like a list of checkboxes. Thus, when the user checks one of the items, it's activated state will be set to true. However, TextViews will not show any visual effects when activated by default. To show a specific background when selected we need to use a list item layout that can display the activated state. One way to do this is to change the background of the ListView item view to a selector and define a Drawable you want to use for the activated state.

For instance:

Adapter code:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, 
    R.array.Planets, R.layout.myitem);
```

myitem.xml:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    style="?android:attr/spinnerItemStyle"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/item_background"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"/>
```

item_background.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/item_selected" android:state_activated="true" />
</selector>
```

Or if you are lazy:

```
ArrayAdapter adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, 
    R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1);
```

**Further reading**

*From Android's documentation it is not entirely obvious that what I said is true, so you might ask if my answer is credible. This section is dedicated to those who seek a credible answer and to the very curious.*

To understand how the list selector works and how it is programmed, we will need to dive into the Android source code. To begin, the meat of the logic of the `ListView` is actually held in a class called `AbsListView` (in case you do not have the source downloaded you can refer to [this](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/5.0.0_r2-robolectric-0/android/widget/AbsListView.java)). Digging into the source of this class we will find a few useful fields/functions pertaining to the selector:

- `mSelector`: This is the Drawable of the selector (the one you specify with `android:listSelector`)
- `mSelectorRect`: This field determines where the selector is drawn and how big the selector is
- `mSelectedPosition`: Stores the index of the selected item (this field is actually declared even deeper down in the class `AdapterView`)
- `positionSelector(...)`: Updates where the selector should be drawn
- `drawSelector(...)`: Draws the selector
- `trackMotionScroll(...)`: Contains the logic of the `ListView`'s scrolling behavior

Now that we have a understanding of the environment, we can finally understand the core logic to the list selector's behavior. It all comes down to these few lines of code in `trackMotionScroll(...)`:

```
boolean trackMotionScroll(int deltaY, int incrementalDeltaY) {
    ...
    if (!inTouchMode && mSelectedPosition != INVALID_POSITION) {
        // if we are not in touch mode and there is a selected item then
        // we do a quick check if the selected item is on screen
        final int childIndex = mSelectedPosition - mFirstPosition;
        if (childIndex >= 0 && childIndex < getChildCount()) {
            // if the selected item is on screen, we move the selector to
            // where the selected item is
            positionSelector(mSelectedPosition, getChildAt(childIndex));
        }
    } else if (mSelectorPosition != INVALID_POSITION) {
        // if we are in touch mode and there is a selected item then
        // we do a quick check if the selected item is on screen
        final int childIndex = mSelectorPosition - mFirstPosition;
        if (childIndex >= 0 && childIndex < getChildCount()) {
            // if the selected item is on screen, we move the selector to
            // where the selected item is
            positionSelector(INVALID_POSITION, getChildAt(childIndex));
        }
    } else {
        // otherwise, if nothing is selected, hide the selector (don't draw it)
        mSelectorRect.setEmpty();
    }
    ...
}
```

*The source snippet above has been edited from the original to include comments.*

It is here where we finally find the logic that explains the behavior observed: The list selector is **only** hidden when `mSelectorPosition == INVALID_POSITION` or, in English, when there are no selected items. Otherwise it is positioned at the selected item if the item is on screen, otherwise no changes are made to it's position.

So when you scroll the `ListView` and the selected item goes off screen, the list selector just stays put in the last location the selected item was explaining the *ghost* list selector observed.

**Final thoughts**

From working with ListViews since it's introduction, I have to say that the entire thing is not very well designed and it can be extremely buggy. I highly recommend using it's successor, the `RecyclerView`, whenever you can.

Comment: Looks like my selector's items wording is a bit misleading.  I'm really trying to understand what's wrong with that default selector whatever name I'll assign to it. Will it help to clarify the problem if I rename `@drawable/item_selected` to `@drawable/item_default`?

Comment: Sorry if my answer wasn't clear. Try changing the code of your `@drawable/item_selected` to the code I posted.

Comment: When I wrote "This problem arises when you give the list selector a default background." I was referring to this line of your list_selector `<item android:drawable="@drawable/item_selected" />`. Since you did not specify any constraints on this item (i.e. `android:state_pressed="true"`), it is the "default" background. I will update my answer with this clarification.

Comment: Yes, I see what item you was referrring to. I don't want to add any constraint to it, it must be default "selector" (I'm reaally lost with  Android terms on the subject, but default selector defines a selection any way, or what  is it?).

Comment: From the documentation `android:listSelector` field on the ListView is used to determine how a selected item looks. But this description is **very** misleading. The way that it should actually be used is to determine how an item should be drawn given a set of states that the item is in.

Comment: You can safely add the `android:state_activated="true"` constraint to the list selector since you specified `android:choiceMode="singleChoice"` on your ListView. This means that a selected item is guaranteed to be activated.

Comment: Does it mean "Never use default item in ListSelector, it's broken and useless" ?

Comment: For the most part yes. But I wouldn't say it's broken per se. It's just not well documented.

Comment: @idunnololz is there any documentation for this to which I can refer and check?

Comment: @idunnololz If I am setting this `android:choiceMode="singleChoice"` then also, its not taking the drawable which I specified for `android:state_activated="true"`. Can you just explain something related to this?

Comment: @Nigam Patro if it is not working then you need to post some code otherwise I can't tell you what is wrong.

Comment: @Nigam Patro as for documentation on this, you can't really refer to the java docs as they are wrong. You can however take a peek inside the source of AbsListView. Look inside the function `trackMotionScroll(...)`. The main things you need to know is that the selector drawable is called `mSelector` and the positioning of the selector is done by `positionSelector(...)`. Inside `trackMotionScroll(...)`, you will find that the selector is only hidden if it does not have a valid position (i.e. `mSelectorPosition == INVALID_POSITION`) which will always be false after an item is selected.

Comment: I will update my answer to include this information.

Comment: @idunnololz this is my selector code `<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/item_pressed" android:state_pressed="true" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/item_selected" android:state_activated="true" />

</selector>` , adapter creation `arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.layout_items,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1);`.

Comment: @idunnololz ListView defined in xml `<ListView
        android:id="@+id/listView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
        android:dividerHeight="0dp"
        android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector" />`

Comment: @idunnololz  Good work. Sure I'd prefer to see something more positive about this selector, but you've proved it's currently impossible.

Comment: @NigamPatro Try using arrayAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.layout_items, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_activated_1); I actually just realized I made a mistake in my answer. I will update it accordingly.

Comment: @idunnololz But, its not showing the drawable which I specified for the activated state.

Comment: @NigamPatro You would need to define your own list item layout then. Look at my updated answer for an example.

Comment: @idunnololz I want to know about the `android:listSelector` property of listview. The thing which you specified is , you set the background for the item which I don't want. Tell me about the `listSelector` not about item background.

Comment: @NigamPatro Unfortunately this is not possible. The thing about the `listSelector` is that it's pretty much unusable to actually show which item is selected due to the way it was coded. Setting the background of the items is just a workaround in a sense but in a different sense, it is the proper way to do things. State of a view in a list should be stored in the individual views themselves and not in the parent view. This is to decrease code coupling (i.e. separate the concern of objects).

Comment: @idunnololz from the starting you are mentioning something, and then changing that thing to other and also controverting your previous comments. Setting a **background** is a work around I know. But, what is the proper use of `listSelector` ?

Comment: @NigamPatro Yes as some point I noticed I made a mistake in my response so I had to fix it in the OP. In terms of proper use of the `listSelector`, you can use it for animating a selection, for instance you can change the color of the item temporarily to show that the user is currenly pressing on an item. However, I would advice against using `listSelector` altogether since it doesn't seem to be very well designed/thought out in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to add android:layerType="software" in ListView.

```
<ListView
    android:layerType="software"
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"
    android:scrollingCache="false"
    android:animationCache="false"
    android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector">
</ListView>
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't help, the above behavior persists.

Comment: I think you should use background instead of it.I test it on my mobile, and it displays hunged color block as you say.It seems like ListView doesn't update the rect of the selector when you scroll.I think there is no way to solve it.